# Export-csv showing system.object[] instead of values

Tags: powershell, formatting

Have the following script that should return Exchange versions of the servers on a domain. However, the output shows the Name columns/field properly, but the Version and Role just have "System.Object[]" in each.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$domain = read-host "Enter the domain"
$ServerArray =@()
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=$($domain),dc=local" -Filter {Name -like '*MBX*'} | Select -Exp Name | sort |
% { 
Write-Host "Processing $_"    
$obj = "" | Select "Name","Version","ServerRole"
$obj.Name = $_
$obj.Version = (Get-ExchangeServer).AdminDisplayVersion
$obj.ServerRole = (Get-ExchangeServer).ServerRole
$ServerArray += $obj
$obj = $null
}
$ServerArray | export-csv c:\users\$env:username\desktop\"$domain-ExchVer".csv -NoType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ExchangeServer` is clearly returning an array of objects here. You have the potential to have more than one Exchange server so I would expect to have more than one result. Also there is no need to call the cmdlet every loop pass. The information is *not likely* to change.

You on the other hand possibly on have the one server? You need to break the array and just get the string back. Not the only approach...

```
$exchangeServerDetails = Get-ExchangeServer | Select -First 1

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=$($domain),dc=local" -Filter {Name -like '*MBX*'} | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
        Sort-Object | ForEach-Object{
            Write-Host "Processing $_"    
            $obj = "" | Select "Name","Version","ServerRole"
            $obj.Name = $_
            $obj.Version = $exchangeServerDetails.AdminDisplayVersion
            $obj.ServerRole = $exchangeServerDetails.ServerRole
            # Pass the completed object down the pipeline. 
            $obj
} | Export-Csv "c:\users\$($env:username)\desktop\$domain-ExchVer.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```